# Return the maximum values of a field whenever another field value is zero

Tags: sql-server

I have a table structure like this:

```
 name     idletime     speed

 RJ14       300           0
 RJ14       360           0
 RJ14       400           0
 RJ14        0            30
 RJ14        50           0
 VJ23       100           0
 VJ23       160           0
 VJ23       200           0
 VJ23        0            50
 VJ23        30           0
```

I want results in this format

```
 name     idletime

 RJ14       400      
 RJ14        50      
 VJ23       200      
 VJ23        30
```

I need a query that can return the maximum values of a field whenever value of another field (speed) is zero. Any suggestions? Thanks.

**EDIT**

When speed of a particular name becomes greater than zero, the `idletime` becomes zero. I need the value of idletime before it became zero every time.

I have tried this query, but it didn't return the expected result.

```
  SELECT NAME ,MAX(idleTime) FROM idletime WHERE speed=0 GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: What means "maximum values"? Aren't you simply selecting all idletimes where speed is 0? I don't see that you are grouping by `name`, so i don't understand "maximum value".

Comment: @TimSchmelter There are gonna be millions of rows and I need the maximum values only not all. Please check the results I mentioned.

Comment: @Mariano Please take a look at the edit

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal: it's getting clearer now, but i'm missing a column which indicates the order, for example a `datetime` column. If there's no `datetime` column you should either change that or use at least the primary key column.

Comment: there is no way to order your data. Do you have a time or id column?

Comment: @AbishekAgarwal, You have mentioned  you need the value of idletime before it became zero every time. Then how does 50 and 30 came into the expected output. could u clarify?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, each row has a unique id.

Comment: @bmsqldev: they are the last values for RJ14 and VJ23, so i think that those should be included.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? In 2012+ there is `LAG` function that may be useful here.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter. Why the last values should be included? you meant that  we have to get the maximum each time after the idletime column becomes 0?

Comment: @bmsqldev I believe `idletime` is always incremental, that's why the last values are expected. But "*the value of idletime before it became zero every time*" remains true, and the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want all maximum idle records ordered by the ID and all which have no non-idle record afterwards?

This is more complicated than i've thought. You can simplify it by using multiple CTE's:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, IdleTime, Speed,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID ASC)
    FROM dbo.TableName t
)
, Idles AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, IdleTime, Speed, RN 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Speed = 0 AND IdleTime <> 0
)
, NonIdles AS
(
    SELECT ID, Name, IdleTime, Speed, RN
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Speed <> 0 AND IdleTime = 0
)
SELECT ID, Name, IdleTime, Speed
FROM Idles i
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Idles i2
    WHERE  i.Name = i2.Name AND i2.RN > i.RN
)
OR EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM NonIdles ni
    WHERE  i.Name = ni.Name AND i.RN + 1 = ni.RN 
)
```

<kbd>[**SQL-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2c73/2/0)</kbd> with your sample data

Comment: This solution is working, but it's taking too much time.

Comment: With an index on `name` it should be efficient

Answer (score 3):

> When `speed` of a particular `name` becomes greater than zero, the `idletime` becomes zero. I need the value of `idletime` before it became zero every time.
>
> > each row has a unique id

**Query**

```
;WITH numberedidletable AS
(
  SELECT id,name,idletime,speed, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name,id) AS RN
  FROM idletable
)

SELECT name,idletime
FROM numberedidletable
WHERE speed = 0 AND
      RN IN (
                (SELECT RN-1
                 FROM numberedidletable tmpnit
                 WHERE speed<>0 AND
                       numberedidletable.name = tmpnit.name)
            UNION ALL
                (SELECT MAX(RN)
                  FROM numberedidletable
                  GROUP BY name)
             )
ORDER BY RN
```

**<kbd>[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07c4c/4)</kbd>**

---

**How it works**

1. First, we create a table adding the `ROW_NUMBER()` (because we can't guarantee the unique id is sequential):

   ```
   ;WITH numberedidletable AS
   (
     SELECT id,name,idletime,speed, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name,id) AS RN
     FROM idletable
   )
   ```
2. Then, we get the row numbers (`RN`) where the next row has a `speed <> 0`:

   ```
               (SELECT RN-1
                FROM numberedidletable tmpnit
                WHERE speed<>0 AND
                      numberedidletable.name = tmpnit.name)
   ```
3. And, all the row numbers for the last items for each `name`:

   ```
           UNION ALL
               (SELECT MAX(RN)
                 FROM numberedidletable
                 GROUP BY name)
   ```
4. To finally select the desired columns of those row numbers:

   ```
   SELECT name,idletime
   FROM numberedidletable
   WHERE speed = 0 AND
         RN IN (

   ... 

                )
   ORDER BY RN
   ```

---

**Assumptions**

- `idletime` is incremental for each part.
- `id` is the unique id

---

**Output**

```
name    idletime
RJ14    400
RJ14    50
VJ23    200
VJ23    30
```

**<kbd>[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07c4c/4)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Excellent work and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a Programmatic Approach for this issue. It worked out for me. Below query picks maximum idle-time when speed = 0 and the First idle-time value in which speed become 0 again from non-zero value.

```
 Create table stack (id varchar(5), id1 int, id2 int)
 INSERT INTO STACK
 VALUES

 ('RJ14'  ,     300     ,      0     ),
 ('RJ14'  ,     360     ,      0     ),
 ('RJ14'  ,     400     ,      0     ),
 ('RJ14'  ,      0      ,      30    ),
 ('RJ14'  ,     50      ,      0     ),
 ('VJ23'  ,     100     ,      0     ),
 ('VJ23'  ,     160     ,      0     ),
 ('VJ23'  ,     200     ,      0     ),
 ('VJ23'  ,      0      ,      50    ),
 ('VJ23'  ,      30     ,      0     )

 declare @stack as table (name varchar(5),idletime int, id2 int, rws int)
 declare @val   as table (name varchar(5),idletime int )

 insert into @stack
 SELECT ID,ID1 idletime, id2, row_number() over(order by id ) as rws
 FROM STACK

 declare @id    int = 1
 declare @count int 
 declare @value int = 0

 select @count = count (*) from @stack

 while (@id <= @count)
 begin

     select @value = ID2 from @stack where rws = @id and id2 <> 0
     if @value <> 0
     begin
         insert into @val
         select name, idletime 
         from @stack
         where rws = @id -1
         union
         select name, idletime from
         @stack where rws = @id + 1
      end  
         select @id    = @id + 1
         select @value = 0
  end

  select *from @val ORDER BY NAME, idletime DESC
```

Here is the SQL-FIDDLE for the Same

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58f88/1)

Comment: Neat approach +1! Not sure if this can occur, as the OP didn't specify, but your solution may return more rows with consecutive `idletime = 0` values http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46128/1

Comment: Yeah it return more values. I thing your solution also did the same

Comment: I think I made sure it didn't with the main `WHERE speed = 0`.. I'm trying to reproduce it, but I can't.